# CSS body background image fixed to full screen even when zooming in/out

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve something like this with CSS:

I'd like to keep the body background image fixed on fullscreen, this is sort of done by the following code:

```
body
{
    background: url(../img/beach.jpg) no-repeat fixed 100% 100%;
}
```

Now I can verify the window is indeed filled up with that image, at least this works on my Firefox 3.6

However, it screwed up when I tried to zoom in/out (ctrl+-/+), the image just is stretched/shrinked as the page zooms.

Is there a better way of doing this purely with CSS? I didn't find a good property for the background-image.

Or should I start thinking about jQuery to manipulate the width and height on the fly? They were both set to 100% so I reckon that should work "as always" :(

Thanks for any suggestion in advance!

Comment: The two values right at the end, the two 100%, refers to the background **position**, not size. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position

Comment: Sad to say those css doesn't work with IE 8... is there any other way to make that work with IE8 & IE7?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've used [these techniques](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) before and they both work well.  If you read the pros/cons of each you can decide which is right for your site.

Alternatively you could use the [full size background image jQuery plugin](http://bavotasan.com/downloads/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/) if you want to get away from the bugs in the above.

Comment: Oops! never thought there would be a jQuery plugin for the exact thing :)

Comment: @Michael I've discovered there's a jQuery plugin for pretty much everything ;)

Answer (score 63):

there is another technique

use

```
background-size:cover
```

That is it
full set of css is

```
body { 
    background: url('images/body-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Latest browsers support the default property.

Answer (score 5):

You can do quite a lot with plain css...the css property `background-size` can be set to a number of things as well as just `cover` as Ranjith pointed out.

The `background-size: cover` setting scales the image to cover the entire screen but may mean that some of the image is off screen if the aspect ratio of the screen and image are different.

A good alternative is `background-size: contain` which resizes the background image to fit the smaller of width and height, ensuring that the whole image is visible but may lead to letterboxing if the aspect ratios are different.

For example:

```
body {
      background: url(/images/bkgd.png) no-repeat rgb(30,30,30) fixed center center;
      background-size: contain;
     }
```

The other options that I find less useful are:
`background-size: length <widthpx> <heightpx>` which sets the absolute size of the background image.
`background-size: percentage <width> <height>` background image is a percentage of the window size.
(see [w3schools.com's page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp))

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your css file:

```
.custom_class
 {
    background-image: url(../img/beach.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

and then, in your .html (or .php) file call this class like that:

```
<div class="custom_class">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code for full page background image when zooming
you just apply the `width:100%` in style/css thats it

`position:absolute; width:100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Use Directly like this

```
.bg-div{
     background: url(../img/beach.jpg) no-repeat fixed 100% 100%;
}
```

or call CSS separately like

```
.bg-div{
    background-image: url(../img/beach.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```