# How can I make background of a div span over the entire page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage right now and I need the background of a div to cover the entire page (100% width).

My problem is that the content of the div should be centered in a 950px div which is centered and the div with the background is placed within a div with 950px width.

I can not figure out how I shoud get this to work. Could somebody please help me.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Can you not have a div with a width of 100% and then another nested inside that's 950px wide and centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is your looking for. Is it something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            .outerDiv { width:100%; background:#DEDEDE; }
            .innerDiv { width:950px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 2px #000000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="innerDiv">
                This is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test, this is a test.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've replaced "text-align:center;" in outerDiv with "margin:0 auto;" in innerDiv as per Pat's.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these techniques in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594512/css-body-background-image-fixed-to-full-screen-even-when-zooming-in-out/3594571#3594571) to get the 100% width background image.  Then to center your content div, you only need something like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 950px;">
    Your content goes right m'ere
</div>
```

What the above does is create a 950px wide div with `0px` of margin on top and bottom and `auto` margins on left and right.  This centers the block level element in its parent according to the [W3C visual formatting](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) model:

> If both 'margin-left' and
>   'margin-right' are 'auto', their used
>   values are equal. This horizontally
>   centers the element with respect to
>   the edges of the containing block.

Comment: You're right, the "margin: 0 auto;" is a better way to do it.  I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Not a problem.  The thing to remember with it is that the element should have a defined width and it doesn't work in IE5 (for that you need to put it in a parent container with `text-align: center`).